# Разрядность чисел в input

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Есть input

```
$html="<input  type='text' size='6' name='valot$name' id='valot$id' class='valot$id' placeholder='{$fieldtitle} от' value='$valsa'/>"
```

Далее данные уходят через "return $html;"

Как сделать чтобы значения вводимые в input(числа) разделялись на пробелы(разрядность), а в "return $html;" отправлялись уже без пробелов(разрядности). То есть человек вводит в input 10000 ему видно было это как 10 000 а в "return $html;" данные инпутов отправлялись уже без пробелов 10000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый простой способ уже был описан на [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27465135/add-space-separator-to-number-in-input-box) пользователем @gyc:

```
$('#number').on("keyup", function() {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/ /g,"");
    this.value = this.value.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ");
});
```

Суть в следующем: просто на каждое нажатие пользователя, с помощью регулярки вставляем пробел в места, где число делится на разряды, и заменяем оригинальное значение инпута.

Если интересуют более сложные способы, то, например [тут](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/auto-formatting-input-value--cms-26745) приведён пример форматирования интупа для конкретной локали.

Что касается PHP-части, то здесь достаточно просто удалить пробелы из числа (и можно ещё на всякий случай привести значение к int):

```
$string = (int)str_replace(' ', '', $_POST['valot']);
```

Comment: С заменой разрядности впринципи проблем нет. А вот как в return передать эти данные без пробелов - это уже интересно.

Comment: @Алерт я же описал в ответе способ превратить такой инпут в обычное число на пхп. В чём сейчас проблема? Вы возможно путаете время выполнения пхп-серипта и JS. Потому что `return $html` в любом случае выдаст только статический html, а форматирование разрядности происходит на клиенте (если я правильно понял задачу).

Answer (score 1):

если вы используете AJAX тогда при отправке парсите это поле `.replace(/\D/g,'')`
Если же вы отправляете на сервер обычно тогда парсить придется на сервере, увы в php я плохо разбираюсь

```js
function razr(){
  var val = parseFloat(this.value.replace(/\D/g,''));
  this.value = val.toLocaleString();
}

valot.addEventListener("input",razr);
```

```html
<input  type='text' size='6' name='valot$name' id='valot' class='valot' placeholder='placeholder'/>
```

123